# Multiple Port Listen Not Working

Tags: c#, sockets, winsock

I have a question about multiple port listen. I wrote this code on CSharp.
I can send a message two ports using this code. It works for once. How can I change this code to work more than once ? The code blocks in here :

**Server Side :**

```
class ListenPorts
{
    Socket[] scon;
    IPEndPoint[] ipPoints;
   internal ListenPorts(IPEndPoint[] ipPoints)
    {
        this.ipPoints = ipPoints;
        scon = new Socket[ipPoints.Length];
    }

    public void beginListen()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ipPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            scon[i] = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            scon[i].Bind(ipPoints[i]);
            Thread thread = new Thread(threadListen);
            thread.Start(scon[i]);
        }

    }

    public void threadListen(object objs)
    {
        Socket scon = objs as Socket;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        EndPoint Remote = (EndPoint)(sender);
        try
        {
            scon.Listen(100);
            Socket newSocket = scon.Accept();
            newSocket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
           // scon.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
       Console.WriteLine(scon.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + "IP {0}: ", Remote.ToString());
    }

}
```

The main method is used to invoke the class to listen to the ports.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
        IPEndPoint ipPoint1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8081);
        IPEndPoint[] ipPoints = new IPEndPoint[2] { ipPoint, ipPoint1 };
        ListenPorts lp = new ListenPorts(ipPoints);
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Listen");
        lp.beginListen();
    }
```

}

**Client Side :**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        //TCP Client

        Console.WriteLine("This is a Client, host name is {0}", Dns.GetHostName());

        //Set the IP address of the server, and its port.
        IPEndPoint ipep1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
        IPEndPoint ipep2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8081);
        string welcome = "Hello! ";

        try
        {
            Socket server1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
           server1.Connect(ipep1);
           server1.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome));
           server1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Socket server2 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
        server2.Connect(ipep2);
        server2.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome));
        server2.Close();

    }
```

}

Comment: There isn't a loop in your `threadListen` serverside, so? You are trying to read data ones.

Comment: Can you help me please about this ? @Jeroen van Langen ?

Comment: Not at the moment. A hint is, put a while surround the `Read` and check the bytesread that the `Read` returns, so you know how much data is read. Don't forget, it's a streaming socket, so you should have something like a protocol prefixed with the size of data you are receiving. While reading, you could receive half or even 2 messages wihtin one read.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I've encountered the same problem @ÖmürCanYurdugül

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop in listener code.

```
try
{

    while (true)
  {
      scon.Listen(100);
      Socket newSocket = scon.Accept();

      var size= newSocket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);

      Console.WriteLine($"Received {size} bytes on socket {scon.LocalEndPoint}");
  }

}
catch (SocketException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
Console.WriteLine(scon.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + "IP {0}: ", Remote.ToString());
```